# Android FirebaseMessagingService UPSTREAM onMessageSent() method called with huge delay

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've migrated my project from Gcm to Fcm as per documentation and I can receive and send messages just fine.

Problem is with the callbacks like :

```
@Override
public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {
    super.onMessageSent(msgId);
    ...
}
```

This gets called in batches with huge delays or immediately after I receive a message from someone else. While this seems to be expected behavior according to the docs, is there any way to immediately determine the status of a sent message?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this for upstream messaging?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be built in functionality. The messages come in batches of 10 according to the documentation (for battery optimization).

I wound up "forcing" the callback to "fire" by sending an empty message back from the recipient to the initial sender (taking advantage of the fact that the callback fires on any received FCM message. This has limitations, of course and is by far NOT ideal but it's the only workaround I could think of.)